# Java RegEx to extract nth group

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract only the first match of the following:

Input (please ignore any possibility to treat it as XML, using XPath, etc. - it's just an example):

```
<city>NYC - New York </city><city>PAR - Paris</city><city>NYC - New York </city><city>MIA - Miami</city>
```

RegEx:

```
(?si).*?(?:NYC\s-\s)([^<]*)
```

As you can see, I already made it lazy, however both New York are being captured. If I leave it greedy, only the last one is being captured.
I need to limit, via regular expression (not via `find` method), to capture only the first one (in fact, the best would be to control which one I want, like the 8th occurrence).
I'm afraid it will make the regular expression very messy.
Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?si)(?:(?:NYC\s-\s)([^<]*).*?){n}
```

Where `n` is the ordinal number of the occurrence you would like to capture.

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wD7jN0/1)

Comment: Thanks, but this RegEx is causing find() to be valid twice when n=1. For n=2, it's fine (only one find).